# Best way to present Javascript rendered material with Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android, notation

I'm trying to make use of Vexflow (http://vexflow.com/) on the Android.  However, I'm stumped as to the best way to display the output.  Is it possible to have a series of webviews and then feed the javascript calls to them?  Something like this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[example image http://paraboxstudios.com/javascript_example.png](http://paraboxstudios.com/javascript_example.png)

Comment: You certainly could, but what's wrong with putting it into one HTML file and using one WebView?

Comment: Hm, I hadn't thought of that.  Is it possible to create and package an HTML file with the app?

Comment: Absolutely. It's pretty easy actually. Look at the docs for [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). In particular methods like [`loadData`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Awesome. If you'd like to post that as an answer I can mark it as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include an HTML file along with any JavaScript files in your assets or resources and then load it in a single [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). The [`loadData`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method may be of particular interest (if you have problems, you can also try the [`loadDataWithBaseURL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method which sometimes gets around some issues).